# Is it more gas efficient to declare variable inside or outside of a for or while loop?

Tags: solidity, gas, local-variables

In solidity does declaring a variable inside a `while` or `for` loop result in that variable being redeclared during each loop iteration? And if so does that make it less gas efficient than say declaring that variable outside the loop and simply re-assigning it inside?

Declare outside and assign inside loop:

```
uint myNumber;
for (uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
  myNumber = i*i;
}
```

Declare and assign inside loop:

```
for (uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
  uint myNumber = i*i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of questions are easiest to just test.

So I created a contract in Remix and ran both of the functions. The first `a` costs 25201 gas and `b` costs 25260 gas. Therefore it's cheaper to to declare the variable outside the loop. This is most likely because of what you said: the variable gets reallocated.

Used contract:

```
contract A {
    function a() public {
        uint myNumber;
        for (uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
            myNumber = i*i;
        }
    }

    function b() public {
        for (uint i=0; i<10; i++) {
            uint myNumber = i*i;
        }
    }
}
```